# E muet avec un s

Tags: poésie

Je voudrais savoir, si un e suivi d’un s que l’on entend reste un e muet

Un exemple tout bête est avec elles. Si je dis :

> Elles auraient

Y a-t-il trois pieds :

> el-lesau-raient /ɛl.zɔ.rɛ/

ou bien quatre :

> el-les-au-raient /ɛ.lə.zɔ.rɛ/

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans le comptage des vers, en poésie (au moins classique), il y a quatre syllabes dans *elles auraient* car -lesau- ne peut pas compter pour une seule syllabe.

Même si en français courant on dira elle-zau-raient (3 syllabes), il faut en poésie dire e-lle-zau-raient.

La règle du e muet n'est valable que s'il est à la fin du mot. Dans ce cas, le s s’interpose, il n’y a donc pas d’élision.

Si tu veux un outil pour compter tes syllabes, utilise [ce site](https://www.scribblab.com/outils/syllaber).

Answer (score 1):

Généralement, si la lettre qui suit le e muet est normalement muette elle-même, alors oui, ce e demeure muet. Si ce n'est pas le cas, la situation peut devenir très complexe car les règles qui régissent la prononciation du e muet sont non seulement très variables d'une région, d'un dialecte, d'une classe sociale, voire d'une personne à l'autre, mais pas particulièrement précises même une fois tous les autres facteurs pris en compte.

Toutefois, dans ce cas précis, le e demeure la plupart du temps totalement muet et le /s/ forme une liaison parfaitement régulière (donc en /z/) avec le mot suivant: /ɛlzɔrɛ/.

Il est *possible* de prononcer cela avec quatre pied, oui (par exemple pour obtenir un pied de plus dans un poème ou une chanson), mais ce n'est pas la prononciation la plus usuelle.